# scripting with eshell

Tags: emacs, eshell

Is there a way to write .sh scripts to be used from eshell buffer? with eshell(elisp) specific commands?

I want `ediff $1 $2` to be executed from my `compare.sh` from within eshell buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `emacsserver` running, just try:

```
emacsclient --eval '(ediff-merge-files "FILE1" "FILE2" nil "NEWFILE")'
```